# Что значит ошибка: "error C2447: missing function header (old-style formal list?)" ?

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Что значит ошибка: "error C2447: missing function header (old-style formal list?)" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, завершили заголовок функции ненужной точкой с запятой или случайно потерли заголовок, оставив бесхозное тело.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s95fcz9b.aspx)